# Rails best practice for getting past 10 entries in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get the sales from the past 10 weeks. I can do that with this method:

```
def past_10_sales(yw)
  past_sales = []
  year_week = yw

  10.times do
    sales = Sales.where(year_week: year_week.previous)

    past_sales << sales unless sales.empty?
    year_week = year_week.previous
  end
  past_sales.flatten
end
```

But now I need this method somewhere else as well and wanted to put it in the `sales.rb` model, but i don't know what the best practice of this would be or if there is something in Rails that makes this better? It feels wrong calling `Sales.where` in the `sales.rb` model...

Edit:
`year_week` is a model with the current year and calendar week. So the current year_week would be 202244. Calling `year_week.previous` gives me `202243`. I'm getting all the sales from a specific calendar week.
This works fine btw.

Edit 2:
I have a model `sales.rb`. in this model i save all the sales. it only matters in which calendar week the sales were made, the exact date does not matter so it looks something like this:

```
create_table "sales" do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "year_week_id"
  etc...
end
```

i also have a model `year_week` which just saves the year and the calendarweek and the id is like this: yearweek (so 202244). there are methods like `def previous` that return the previous year_week.

What i now want is all the sales form the past 10 weeks. so i call this:

```
    sales = Sales.where(year_week: year_week.previous)

    past_sales << sales unless sales.empty?
    year_week = year_week.previous
```

10 times because this way it gets all the sales in the past 10 weeks but it just doesn't feel right and i was wondering if/what better way there is for this.

Comment: Can you Please add the value of yw? 
and you can simply create an array of values and get results in a single query like 
`past_sales = Sales.where(year_week: [year_week_array])`

Comment: Provided you actually have a sensible date/time column on the model that you can query you can simply pass a Range of dates to get a `WHERE column_name BETWEEN x AND y` query. For example `Sale.where(created_at: time.advance(weeks: -10)..time)`.

Comment: "It feels wrong calling Sales.where in the sales.rb model..." - what should feel even more wrong is that this code causes 10 database queries. Its unclear from the code or description what this code is even supposed to do or what the underlying schema is. If you can provide a clear example of the expected input/output its a lot easier to answer this question.

Comment: I would also remove the "best practices" mention - that will get the question closed as opinion based. Best practices aren't relevant or applicable to every single programming task. Except not giving yourself a N+1 query issue.

Comment: @max i added information. and no need to get so passiv aggressiv.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it in the below way:

```
def past_10_sales(yw)
  year_week = yw.previous
  past_sales = Sales.where(year_week: (year_week-9..year_week.to_a))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to work with a bigint you can do something like:

```
starting_week = Time.current.advance(weeks: -10).strftime("%Y%V").to_i
Sale.where(
  year_week: starting_week.. 
)
```

This uses ISO weeks. Otherwise use `%U` or `%W`. See [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime). Of course using `date_trunc('week', sales.created_at)` or the equivilent database function would make this column reduntant unless the week isn't actually the same as the calender week its created.